# Convert Table to Multidimensional Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I know that there must be some simple and elegant way to do this, but I'm drawing a blank.

I have a table (or group of key value pairs)

```
id,val
64664,68
64665,65
64666,53
64667,68
64668,6
64668,27
64668,33
64669,12
```

In most cases there is one value per id. In some cases there are multiples.
I want to end up with each id with multiple values represented as an array of those values

something like this:

```
[ 64664 => 68,
64665 => 65, 
64666 => 53, 
64668 =>[6,27,33],
64669 => 12
]
```

Any brilliant ideas?

Comment: Is this on text file ?

Comment: What do you mean a table? Is it a csv file?

Comment: could be a text file or an existing hash

Comment: I meant table in a generic sense. It's two columns of data. Could be a SQL table or Excel spreadsheet or CSV file. It's just multiple rows of two column records.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to merge two hashes. Using [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), you can get what you want.

```
tbl = [
  [64664, 68],
  [64665, 65],
  [64666, 53],
  [64667, 68],
  [64668, 6],
  [64668, 27],
  [64668, 33],
  [64669, 12],
]

# Convert the table to array of hashes
hashes = tbl.map { |id, val|
  {id => val}
}

# Merge the hashes
hashes.inject { |h1, h2|
  h1.merge(h2) { |key,old,new|
    (old.is_a?(Array) ? old : [old]) << new
  }
}
# => {64664=>68, 64665=>65, 64666=>53, 64667=>68, 64668=>[6, 27, 33], 64669=>12}
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit, To be honest, I didn't know about `Hash#merge` until I saw your answer in another question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
values = [
  [64664, 68],
  [64665, 65],
  [64666, 53],
  [64667, 68],
  [64668, 6],
  [64668, 27],
  [64668, 33],
  [64669, 12],
]

# When key not present, create new empty array as default value
h = Hash.new{|h,k,v| h[k]=[]} 
values.each{|(k,v)| h[k] << v}

p h #=>{64664=>[68], 64665=>[65], 64666=>[53], 64667=>[68], 64668=>[6, 27, 33], 64669=>[12]}
```